# Docker link containers

Tags: nginx, docker

I need to setup nginx-proxy container to forward requests to the container with my app. I use the following commands to start containers:

```
# app
docker run -d -p 8080:2368 \
  --name app \
  app

# nginx
docker run -d -p 80:8080 \
  --name nginx-proxy \
  jwilder/nginx-proxy
```

But when I try to access port 80 on my server, I get `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`. It's clear for me that nginx container is forwarding not the port I want because on server port 8080 I can access the app.
I tried using `network` like this:

```
# network
docker network create -d bridge net

# app
docker run -d -p 8080:2368 \
  --name app \
  --network net \
  app

# nginx
docker run -d -p 80:8080 \
  --name nginx-proxy \
  --network net \
  jwilder/nginx-proxy
```

But the result seems to be the same.
I need to understand how to make nginx container proxy requests from server port 80 to my app.

Answer (score 1):

You are exposing port 8080 in the nginx container on port 80 on your local system. But according to the docs of this container, nginx listens on port inside the container.

```
# nginx
docker run -d -p 80:80 \
  --name nginx-proxy \
  --network net \
  jwilder/nginx-proxy
```

Additionally you need to configure the nginx container to connect to your application, e.g. like below (the nginx container reads the configratuion from the environment variables set on other containers to build its configuration)

```
# network
docker network create -d bridge net

# app
docker run -d -p 8080:2368 \
  --name app \
  --network net \
  -e VIRTUAL_HOST=app.local \
  -e VIRTUAL_PORT=2368 \
  app

# nginx
docker run -d -p 80:8080 \
  --name nginx-proxy \
  --network net \
  -v /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro \
  jwilder/nginx-proxy
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I understood and followed the first item (regarding nginx listening inside the container). Now I can reach the server, but get 503 nginx page, looks like nginx container has no access to the app container, so can't forward its port. `VIRTUAL_HOST` env var for app container from the second item doesn't help, can you please explain this part deeper?

Comment: You need to tell the nginx container to tell where it should forward the requests. This is done by setting environment variables on you application container. By default jwilder/nginx-proxy will redirect to port 80, but your application is listening on port 2368, you need to manually specify port 2368. I've updated my answer.